# Hello World on visual studio code

Tags: javascript

My attempt is giving me an error that I cannot find. Why do I need `[js]`? And how do I compile using Visual Studio Code?

```
[js]<!DOCTYPE HTML>[js];
<html>
<body>
<p>Header...</p>
<script>
alert('Hello, World!')
</script>
<p>...Footer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Error states:

```
severity: 'Error'
message: '';' expected.'
at: '1,15'
source: 'js'
```

Comment: what is the extension of the file?

Comment: I don't see why this is linked to VSCode ?

Comment: @DanielA.White .js

Comment: @kube because I am coding in visual studio code

Comment: You don't compile HTML and JavaScript. You load it into a browser. You have exactly one line of JavaScript in your post, and the error is at character 15 in that line, and the error message tells you exactly what's wrong with that line. What more can we help you with?

Comment: `[js]<!DOCTYPE HTML>[js];` what the heck is that `[js]` rubbish?

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Code is more of an advanced text editor. By default it does not have a set compiler (Javascript does not compile). I'm not sure why it would recommend using the [js] tags. Below is your code on JsFiddle working as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nhawdge/db6tzgey/

```
<body>
<p>Header...</p>
<script>
alert('Hello, World!')
</script>
<p>...Footer</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You! Is jsfiddle where you practice HTML and javascript?

Comment: Jsfiddle can certainly be used for practice, but I prefer it for sharing to the open world. I write most of my Javascript in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score -4):

The only JavaScript in your file is the `alert` function call. The rest is HTML.

VS code is treating your file as a JavaScript file with the JS extension.